# Fetch the last modified date of all the workflow from the Repository using pmrep / pmcmd command

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud, informatica-powerexchange

I want to fetch details of workflow with its properties from a specific folder using `pmrep` command.

The output should contains

- the workflow name
- the import date time or last saved date time

Below is the repository image
[image: Repository image]

I am looking for an output like below in a text file when command run on unix with workflow name and the date time when it got imported or the last saved date.

Workflow name date timestamp

```
wf_abc_FF 12/07/2020 12:30:35
wf_ab_FF 12/07/2020 12:30:35
wf_ac_FF 12/07/2020 12:30:35
wf_c_FF 12/07/2020 12:30:35
```

Comment: you can connect to infa repo DB and get that. so use some command utility like 'sqlplus' for oracle. Much easier...

Comment: @KoushikRoy  tell me how to do with command line using pmrep or pmcmd command

Comment: pmcmd probably cant be used. pls use a shell script.